# Repeating timerfd event works with epoll and not with poll

Tags: c, linux, timer, polling

I am implementing a timer using timerfd. This is a relative timer that I just need to repeat forever at the rate it is set to. I want to poll on this event and originally tried using poll. When I did this, I would see the timer event the first time and then never again. However, when I changed to using epoll (no change at all to how the timerfd was set up) it works as expected.

Here is the code with poll:

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    struct pollfd p;
    int timerfd;
    struct itimerspec timerValue;

    /* clear pollfd */
    bzero(&p, sizeof(p));

    /* set timerfd */
    timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    if (timerfd < 0) {
        printf("failed to create timer fd\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(&timerValue, sizeof(timerValue));
    timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    /* set events */
    p.fd = timerfd;
    p.revents = 0;
    p.events = POLLIN;

    /* start timer */
    if (timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &timerValue, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("could not start timer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* wait for events */
    while (1) {
        int numEvents = poll(&p, 1, -1);
        if (numEvents > 0) {
            int timersElapsed = 0;
            (void) read(p.fd, &timersElapsed, 8);
            printf("timers elapsed: %d\n", timersElapsed);
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

And here is the code with epoll:

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    struct epoll_event epollEvent;
    struct epoll_event newEvents;
    int timerfd;
    int epollfd;
    struct itimerspec timerValue;

    /* set timerfd */
    timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
    if (timerfd < 0) {
        printf("failed to create timer fd\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(&timerValue, sizeof(timerValue));
    timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    /* set events */
    epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    epollEvent.events = EPOLLIN;
    epollEvent.data.fd = timerfd;
    epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timerfd, &epollEvent);

    /* start timer */
    if (timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &timerValue, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("could not start timer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* wait for events */
    while (1) {
        int numEvents = epoll_wait(epollfd, &newEvents, 1, 0);
        if (numEvents > 0) {
            int timersElapsed = 0;
            (void) read(epollEvent.data.fd, &timersElapsed, 8);
            printf("timers elapsed: %d\n", timersElapsed);
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong with poll? Maybe it is not meant to be used this way with a timerfd? Thank you.

Comment: Your poll() code works fine for me. Try looking for anything suspicious when you run the code with the strace tool.

Comment: I tried your cdoe as well and it works fine. I ran it on Linux 3.13.

Comment: @nos - I ran my poll() code with strafe and the problem seems to be that the poll() file descriptor is changing on the second call. So the first time poll() is called, the fd value is 3 (which is was timer_createfd creates). However, the second time it is called, the fd value is 0. `poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}]) ... poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295 ... blocks forever`.

Comment: When I reassign the fd by doing `p.fd = timerfd' again after the read() call then it works. Alternatively if I simply omit the read, then the event seems to not get cleared and it just keeps occurring, regardless of the timer period.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is an old question, but nevertheless. The problem lies in these lines of code:

```
   int timersElapsed = 0;
   (void) read(p.fd, &timersElapsed, 8);
   printf("timers elapsed: %d\n", timersElapsed);
```

`int timersElapsed` is 4 bytes. Reading 8 bytes into this results in a stack overflow, giving unpredictable behaviour.

Changing `timersElapsed` to a `long int` and fixing the printf did the trick for me.

```
   long int timersElapsed = 0;
   (void) read(p.fd, &timersElapsed, 8);
   printf("timers elapsed: %ld\n", timersElapsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Fedora (or my installation of Fedora). That system is running 3.16, and poll() does not work.

However, on a separate Ubuntu installation with 3.13, the poll() code above works just fine. As I will be using Ubuntu in the future anyway, I will not try to track down the issue on Fedora. Though I am curious if others are seeing this same issue on Fedora systems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

After debugging, the root cause in poll example is that
timerValue should be declared as uint64_t.

```
 - int timersElapsed = 0;
 + uint64_t timersElapsed = 0;
```

The man page of timerfd_create() describes this.

```
   Operating on a timer file descriptor
       The file descriptor returned  by  timerfd_create()  supports  the  following
       operations:
       read(2)
              If the timer has already expired one or more times since its settings
              were last modified using timerfd_settime(), or since  the  last  suc‐
              cessful read(2), then the buffer given to read(2) returns an unsigned
              8-byte integer (uint64_t) containing the number of  expirations  that
              have  occurred.   (The  returned value is in host byte order—that is,
              the native byte order for integers on the host machine.)
```